# package.json Just creates a file not Execute

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, bin, npm-cli

This is my add-cli.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Extracting the command line arguments
const args = process.argv.slice(2);

// Function to add numbers
function addNumbers(numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0);
}

// Checking if arguments are provided
if (args.length === 0) {
    console.log("Please provide numbers to add. Example: add-cli 2 3");
} else {
    const sum = addNumbers(args);
    console.log("Sum:", sum);
}
`
```

This is my package.josn
    `{ "name": "add-cli", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "A CLI tool to add numbers.", "main": "add-cli.js", "bin": "./add-cli.js", "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }, "author": "Your Name", "license": "MIT" }`

Now when i run `./add-cli 2 3`
It doesnt log 5 but creates a new files named 2 and 3 and brings cursor to add-cli.js file

I was learning to build a cli for npm and i saw that using bin we can make a command that can be used to execute that linked file.

P.S. -  It works with node ./add-cli.js 2 3

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or screen recording of what you mean? It doesn't make any sense to me, especially the part about "bringing the cursor to the add-cli.js file", in a terminal that doesn't make sense to say. Also, running `./add-cli` should do nothing at all (other than telling you there is no such command) unless you also have an extensionless file in the folder because that's not how `bin` works.